# Bash. Недостатки интерпретации сценариев

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

Какие недостатки несёт интерпретация сценариев? Почему в сценариях не реализуется
поддержка чисел с плавающей
запятой?

Comment: У вас опять два разных вопроса. Один в названии, второй в теле вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Высокую аддиктивность и попытки использовать bash не по на назначению. )

Вот именно потому, что bash не предназначен для вычислений, но при этом внешних способов - множество, например `bc <<< 'scale=4;1/3'`